How to implement rule based transitive closure?
Given a relation L, we can make the symmetric closure using rules as follows:
L = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
L /. {x_, y_} :> Splice[{{x, y}, {y, x}}] /; MemberQ[L, {x, y}]

And this yields:
{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}}

There is, whenever there is {x,y} it will "add" {y,x} to the list. Is there a way to implement the transitive closure of L using rules just like I did for the symmetric closure? I tried the following:
L/.{x_,y_}:>(Splice[{{x,y},{y,z_},{x,z}}]/;SubsetQ[L,{{x,y},{y,z}}])

And:
L /. L :> (Join[L, {x_, z_}] /; (SubsetQ[L, {{x, y}, {y, z}}]))

But they don't work.

EDIT: I guess I did it! In a very weird way which I'm not sure if it's purely rule based but it seems to work!
L={{1,2},{2,3},{2,4}};       
i=0;     
j=0;
L/. ({x_,y_}):>(j++;Splice@Join[{{x,y}},{x,#[[2]]}&/@g[j]])/; i++;g[i]=Cases[L,{y,_}];MemberQ[L,{x,y}])

Which yields:
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}

As desired.
To do this, I had to make a small experiment to understand in which order the x:>y /; P computes what is asked. I used a previous code I was making:
L={{1,2},{2,3},{4,5}};
T={};
a=0;
b=0;
c=0;
L/. (a++;AppendTo[T,\[Alpha][a]];{x_,y_}):>(b++;AppendTo[T,\[Beta][b]];Splice[{{x,y},{y,x}}])/;(c++;AppendTo[T,\[Gamma][c]];MemberQ[L,{x,y}])
T

Which yields:
{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}}

{\[Alpha][1],\[Gamma][1],\[Gamma][2],\[Gamma][3],\[Beta][1],\[Beta][2],\[Beta][3]}

So now we see what is going on. It seems Mathematica looks at x:>y /; P and computes x once and then it executes the test P for each element in $L$, and then it executes y whenever P was true. I kinda adapted from this experiment to make the previous code.

I couldn't find a simple Rule to achieve your goal. In such cases, I will make functional approach rather than pattern-matching. Then FixPoint[] will automatically take closures.
Clear["Global`*"];
L = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};

baseSet = Union[Flatten[L]]

(* {1, 2, 3} *)

addReflexive[L_List] := Union[L, Reverse /@ L];

addTransitive[L_List] := 
 Union[L, 
  Join @@ Flatten[
    Table[Outer[List, Cases[L, {a_, x} :> a], 
      Cases[L, {x, b_} :> b]], {x, baseSet}], 1]];

FixedPoint[addTransitive[addReflexive[#]] &, L]

(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}} *)


I guess I did it! Although I'm not sure if this is purely rule based. Take a look in the edit.

I believe the following implements a straight-forward (and likely not-optimized) version of Warshall's Algorithm.
warshall[list_] := Module[
   {n = Max@Flatten@list, mat},
   mat = SparseArray[{list -> 1, {i_, i_} -> 1}, {n, n}];
   Do[mat = Table[
        If[mat[[i, j]] == 1, 1, If[mat[[i, k]] == mat[[k, j]] == 1, 1, 0]],
        {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}],
     {k, 1, n}];
   mat = Position[mat - DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]], 1];
   Union[list, mat]
  ]

You can see that creates the transitive closure of the set:
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {1, 1}}
warshall@list
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}} *)

You can combine this with
symmetrize[list_] := Union[list, Reverse /@ list]
reflexize[list_] := Union[list, Table[{i, i}, {i, 1, Max@Flatten@list}]]

(also possibly unoptimized) to complete the equivalence relation:
FixedPoint[reflexize@*symmetrize@*warshall, list]
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 4}} *)


I guess I did it! Although I'm not sure if this is purely rule based. Take a look in the edit.

@RedBanana Yeah, I only noticed the "rule-based" stipulation after I'd written the answers!

One could also use Mathematica's built-in graph functionality. First turn the list into a directed graph:
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {1, 1}};
graph = DirectedGraph[Rule @@@ list];


Then run
TransitiveClosureGraph[graph]


Finally, we can extract the ordered pairs using
List @@@ EdgeList@TransitiveClosureGraph[graph]
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}} *)

Unfortunately, this removes any reflexive points (i.e., ordered pairs of the form $(k,k)$), so they will need to be put back in by hand. In addition, in version 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019), TransitiveClosureGraph kills the kernel if its input is a disconnected graph, so this needs to be modified for such cases.  In that case, we can split apart the graph into its (weakly) connected components and run the transitive closure on each.  We can package this all together as
transClosure[list_] := Module[{graph = DirectedGraph[Rule @@@ list]},
  If[WeaklyConnectedGraphQ[graph],
    List @@@ EdgeList@TransitiveClosureGraph[graph],
    (transClosure /@ WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[graph])~Flatten~1
   ]
  ]

Then,
transClosure[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {1, 1}}]
DirectedGraph[Rule @@@ %, PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled"]
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}} *)


and
transClosure[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {5, 6}}]
DirectedGraph[Rule @@@ %, PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled"]
(* {{2, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {5, 6}, {3, 6}, {3, 5}} *)



I guess I did it! Although I'm not sure if this is purely rule based. Take a look in the edit.
